# Is there a solution to Update Unity Slider Value based on Text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to Update unity slider.value based upon text value.

For example, I'm receiving from a server a string value like "100", and based on this text I would like to be shown also in a slider such as value of 100. One thing to mention, the text value will be received when the play button is pressed. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and the [tour]. Currently, question is asking for tutoring / general guidance, which is often considered off-topic here. I'd recommend to do some research on tutorials with words like "client server communication unity3d" to find some tutorials. If you have a specific code that you started and doesn't work, edit your question to provide a [mcve] and relevant information, to show that you've already done some research.

Comment: As a general comment, idea would be to have some communication socket opened/being listened to when you click your play button. I imagine the function to open the socket and the callback function would be in a global invisible game object. This object would also have a reference to the slider, thus being able to update it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following script in order to change the value of the slider:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SetValue : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference to the slider you want to set
    public Slider slider;
    Text myText;
    private string m_value = myText.text;

    // Called once the button is clicked
    public void OnClick()
    {
        //Converts the string into a float, and sets it to be the new slider value
        slider.value = float.Parse(m_value);
    }
}
```

now you could put this script on the button and reference it so that it would be executed once you click the button

[e.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM5m0.png)

hope that helps :)